# Jest error TypeError: (0 , _jest.test) is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs

I get the error:

> TypeError: (0 , _jest.test) is not a function

when trying to use `npm test`.

I think it could be related to configurations. How can I fix this problem?

#### File *sum.js*

```
function sum (a, b) {
  return a + b
}

export default sum
```

#### File ***tests**/sum.test.js*

```
import sum from '../src/sum.js'
import { test, expect } from 'jest'

test('adds 1 + 2 to equal 3', () => {
  expect(sum(1, 2)).toBe(3)
})
```

#### File *package.json*

```
"devDependencies": {
    "babel-eslint": "7.1.1",
    "eslint": "3.18.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "6.10.0",
    "standard": "9.0.2",
    "webpack": "2.2.1",
    "jest": "21.0.1",
    "jest-cli": "21.0.1",
    "babel-jest": "21.0.0",
    "regenerator-runtime": "0.11.0"
},
```

and

```
"scripts": {
    "test": "standard && jest",
    "format": "standard --fix",
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --config webpack.config.dev.js",
    "build": "webpack --config webpack.config.prod.js"
},
```

Answer (score 8):

Remove this line:

```
import { test, expect } from 'jest'
```

You don't need to import anything from Jest. See [example](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/getting-started.html).

Comment: Just to add to this answer: I also had this issue using create-react-app with jest testing. A linter marks `expect` as undefined if you don't import it, but this error occurs if you do. `expect` is defined by jest and doesn't need explicitly imported.

Comment: @JessB This sounds like a bad joke. `jest` provides a globally usable `test`, which is fine. It seems to also `export` some `test`, which is broken, but has to be imported, for linter or flow to work.

Answer (score 0):

I've got it running with flow using

```
import expect from "expect";
const test = window.test;
```

Maybe it helps you, too. It seems to make flow treat them both as `any`, which is far from perfect, but at least the other parts of the file can be checked.

---

A slightly better "solution" is to make an own file `my-test.test.js` containing

```
export const test = window.test;
export const expect = window.expect;

test("dummy", () => {});
```

and use it like

```
import {test, expect} from '../my/my-test.test';
```

This concentrates the ugliness in a single file.