# TypeError: (0 , _react.test) is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I created a react project with create-react-app some times ago and i wanted to add some test with jest. I read that Jest comes with create-react-app, but when i try to run the simple test that comes with the project by typing "yarn test", i have this error message: **TypeError: (0 , _react2.test) is not a function**

The test:

```
import React from 'react';
import { render, screen, expect, test} from '@testing-library/react';
import App from './App';

test('renders learn react link', () => {
  render(<App />);
  const linkElement = screen.getByText(/learn react/i);
  expect(linkElement).toBeInTheDocument();
});
```

The result:

[image]

My package.json

```
{
  "name": "test-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.11.4",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^4.11.2",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.14.1",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.7",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.1.9",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
    "web-vitals": "^2.0.1"
    },
    "scripts": {
      "start": "react-scripts start",
      "build": "react-scripts build",
      "test": "react-scripts test",
      "eject": "react-scripts eject",
      "lint": "eslint . --ext .js,.jsx",
      "lint-fix": "npm run lint -- --fix"
    },
    "eslintConfig": {
      "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
      ]
    },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "^7.28.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.24.0"
  }
}
```

Does anyone know what i am missing ? Thank you !

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Jest error TypeError: (0 , \_jest.test) is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46090107/jest-error-typeerror-0-jest-test-is-not-a-function)

Comment: Thank you for the answer, yes that was it ! Thanks a lot